# saveOrder is triggered twice intermittently

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am facing an issue with intermittent duplicate orders.

The payment gateway is SecurePay (Australia) however by looking at the logs, the problem seems to be the codebase since I can see the following (addresses obscured):

```
./ssl_access_log.www10.1:8.8.8.8 - - [05/Nov/2013:01:18:32 +1100] "POST /checkout/onepage/saveOrder/ HTTP/1.1" 200 30 "https://foobar/checkout/onepage/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36" 2444 2204
./ssl_access_log.www10.1:8.8.8.8 - - [05/Nov/2013:01:18:42 +1100] "POST /checkout/onepage/saveOrder/ HTTP/1.1" 200 30 "https://foobar/checkout/onepage/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36" 2444 2204
```

So something is triggering saveOrder twice usually within a 10 second period so this is not a front-end issue where the user is clicking the button twice.

There is no one step checkout installed - it's a standard Magento one page checkout.

**Edit: This is NOT a front-end issue where the user can click the button twice**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although everything was done on the Magento side to ensure this problem is fixed, nothing helped. But grepping through server logs indicated that the issue was with an incorrectly setup CloudFlare - all smooth sailing now.

Comment: I am suffering from a problem that seems very similar (also using CloudFlare). What was the incorrect configuration?

Comment: @erikkallen I don't remember clearly but I believe it was using filters to disable most of the CloudFlare functionalities based on the URL (if it contains 'checkout' 'cart' or similar, disable cache, disable everything). Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the submit order button has no type specified but has a js action on it:

```
<button onclick="submitOrder()">Sumbit order</button>
```

Then the form is submitted and the js action is performed.
try to add `type="button"` on it.

Comment: how would this explain why it's intermittent across different browsers?

Comment: I will take a look into this though, thanks.

Comment: @FrancisKim. Not all browsers interpret this the same way. On IE i think the default type is "button" and on FF is "submit"

Comment: button is set to `type="submit"` which I think is correct. There are no other JS bound to that button except for the magento default `onclick="review.save();"`

Comment: @FrancisKim. That's exacly what I was saying. `review.save` will submit the form, and `type="submit"` will submit the form again...Change the type to "button"

Comment: wow, ok now it makes sense. I will make that change now.

Comment: Looks like the Magento default button is also type="submit"... does that mean Magento out of the box will have this intermittent issue? Just a little confused...

Comment: @FrancisKim. That's a good point. I have no answer for that.

Comment: I have followed your advice and have changed this regardless

Comment: actually it turns out that the form tag around the default Magento submit order button is set to return false anyway.

Comment: I believe even if this button is hit twice, the way Magento is coded - it won't generate 2 orders.

Answer (score 1):

What often happens is that the user actually clicks twice.

To avoid that, you could disable the submit order button right after it has been clicked using Javascript.

I have seen that in place in many shops.

Comment: There is proper frontend validation to stop this actually. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you have some html validation plugins installed. One badly programmed plugin (can't remember it's name) fires the same http request again to load the content for the validation.